# Health Check Fails - HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've enabled HTTP2-only for my APIs. However, when attempting to use health checks I get the following error

HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint.

Setup looks like this

Kestrel:

```
"Kestrel": {
"EndpointDefaults": {
  "Protocols": "Http2",
  "Http": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:5020"
  }
}
```

},

Health Check:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomHealthCheck(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var sqlOptions = services.GetOptions<SqlOptions>("ConnectionStrings");
    var rabbitMqOptions = services.GetOptions<RabbitMqOptions>("RabbitMq");

    services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddSqlServer(sqlOptions.DefaultConnection)
        .AddRabbitMQ(rabbitConnectionString:
            $"amqp://{rabbitMqOptions.UserName}:{rabbitMqOptions.Password}@{rabbitMqOptions.HostName}");

    services.AddHealthChecksUI(setup =>
    {
        setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(60); // time in seconds between check
        setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Basic Health Check", "/healthz");
    }).AddInMemoryStorage();

    return services;
}

public static WebApplication UseCustomHealthCheck(this WebApplication app)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz",
            new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
                ResultStatusCodes =
                {
                    [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
                }
            })
        .UseHealthChecksUI(options =>
        {
            options.ApiPath = "/healthcheck";
            options.UIPath = "/healthcheck-ui";
        });

    return app;
}
```

Dotnet 6.

Comment: Hi @Matt, Did you use windows operation? From .NET 5 it has breaking changes to enable HTTP/2 over Transport Layer Security (TLS) on Windows.  Two requirements need to be met:

Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation (ALPN) support, which is available starting with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.
A set of ciphers compatible with HTTP/2, which is available starting with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Thank you, Rena. I've ensured my Win10 machine is up to date and checked the registry to ensure TLS1.2 was enabled. It doesn't seem to resolve it. I think I need to find a way to override the health check client to use HTTP2 only.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this by telling the health check client to specifically use HTTP version 2.0 with the following code.

```
        services.AddHealthChecksUI(setup =>
        {
            setup.ConfigureApiEndpointHttpclient((sp, client) =>
            {
                client.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);
            });
            setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(60); // time in seconds between check
            setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Basic Health Check", "/healthz");
        })
        .AddInMemoryStorage();
```

Comment: I used your solution too. Another fix was to change "Protocols": "Http2" setting to "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2" in appsettings.json file